# How to use Func from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, func

What I'm trying to do, is to call a specific function for a specific Key.
For example, if the is key is '+', I want to call Sum function.
I already created a Dictionary, and added a Key and a function.

```
Func<int, int, int> Sum = (a, b) => a + b;
Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>> operations = new Dictionary<char, Func<int, int, int>>()
operations.Add('+', Sum);
```

I don't understand how to pass a values to my Sum Func, and how to store an answer somewhere.

Comment: We don't really have enough context to help you. Presumably you'd extract the delegate from the dictionary, and then you could call it with whatever values you have, and do whatever you want with the result... without knowing more about where you're stuck, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how to pass a values to my Sum Func, and how to store an answer somewhere.

```
var operation = operations['+'];
var result = operation(1, 2); // yields 3
```

<sup>([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N8WY5U))</sup>

If you want to emphasize that `operation` is a delegate rather than a "regular" method, you can write `operation.Invoke(1, 2)`  instead of `operation(1, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't obvious)